# Small basic turtle MoveTo error "Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal."

Tags: turtle-graphics, smallbasic

This code appears to throw an exception "Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal."

Somehow changing variables y1, y2, x removes an error. 
For example, y2 from 41 to 38.

How can I fix this?

```
Turtle.Speed = 10
x = 10
y1 = 42
y2 = 41
Turtle.Angle = 180
Turtle.MoveTo(x, y2)
Turtle.MoveTo(x, y1)
```

Error trace:

```
in System.Decimal..ctor(Double value)
in System.Decimal.op_Explicit(Double value)
in Microsoft.SmallBasic.Library.Primitive.op_Implicit(Double value)
in Microsoft.SmallBasic.Library.Turtle.MoveTo(Primitive x, Primitive y)
in _SmallBasicProgram._Main()
```

The same in both 1.0 and 1.2 versions.

Comment: Maybe an underflow error in the source in the conversion back to Primitive: `MoveTo(x,y)` does some math to generate a `Turn/Move` pair (and the values generated at converted to Primitive at these call sites). Decimal values have a *fixed precision* and the ctor will throw an exception if the (supplied double) cannot be exactly represented.

Comment: This appears to be an issue in the `Primitive` itself: `new Primitive((Decimal) primitiveDouble)` .. regardless of any underflows ..

Comment: @user2864740, still did not get it, why it does not appear with all numbers and how to fix it.

Comment: There is no way to fix it (other than choosing different values) without fixing the Smallbasic Primitive type. It might be possible to *avoid* the issue with using Turn/Move explicitly. Here is a trivial example of a failing C# program: `double x = double.MinValue; decimal f = (decimal)x;`

Comment: @user2864740, where can I see a source code? (seems like you can see it)

Comment: I used dotPeek from ReSharper (it's a free tool). There are various alternatives as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the SmallBasic (in version 1.2) Primitive-from-double implementation is flawed. Here is how a double is converted to a Primitive.

```
new Primitive((Decimal) primitiveDouble);
```

However, this is an *unsafe* operation as not all values of a double can be (precisely) represented. In these cases the cast to a Decimal will throw an Exception.

Here is a trivial way to reproduce such an exception in C#:

```
double x = double.MinValue; // [smallest] denormalized value
decimal f = (decimal)x;
```

This happens in the `MoveTo(x,y)` operation which does trigonometry math to turn the `MoveTo` into a `Turn`+`Move` combination. For some inputs (and where the turtle is), such will result in doubles that cannot be [safely] turned into decimal values.

Using `Turn`+`Move` *explicitly* will avoid the problematic math and thus should avoid the problem - at least in this particular case.

For reference, here is the decompiled source of MoveTo:

```
/// <summary>
/// Turns and moves the turtle to the specified location.  If the pen is down, it will draw a line as it moves.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">The x co-ordinate of the destination point.</param>
/// <param name="y">The y co-ordinate of the destination point.</param>
public static void MoveTo(Primitive x, Primitive y)
{
  double d = (double) ((x - Turtle.X) * (x - Turtle.X) + (y - Turtle.Y) * (y - Turtle.Y));
  if (d == 0.0)
    return;
  double num1 = System.Math.Sqrt(d);
  double num2 = System.Math.Acos((double) (Turtle.Y - y) / num1) * 180.0 / System.Math.PI;
  if ((bool) (x < Turtle.X))
    num2 = 360.0 - num2;
  double num3 = num2 - (double) ((int) Turtle.Angle % 360);
  if (num3 > 180.0)
    num3 -= 360.0;
  Turtle.Turn((Primitive) num3); // goes boom here..
  Turtle.Move((Primitive) num1); // ..or here
}
```

Comment: Seems like the solution is to make it this way 
Turtle.Speed = 10
x = 10
y1 = 42
y2 = 41
Turtle.Angle = 180

Turtle.X = x
Turtle.Y = y2
Turtle.MoveTo(x, y1).    As you said explicitely

Comment: If/As that works, it is because the residue from the first turtle MoveTo is cleaned up. Note that the MoveTo takes into account the *current* turtle's position: and the first MoveTo call did not set the position *exactly* to 10/41. However, explicitly setting the X/Y of the turtle "resets" the location to the integer values so the second MoveTo does not fail due to math underflow in the conversion. YMMV.

Comment: I am very impressed that somebody started with a turtle and got as far as diagnosing this bug.  His real name might be a mystery for many more years.